# Including .tex file to LyX document

Tags: lyx, include

Is it possible to write pure latex to a separate file and then include that in the LyX document. What are the pros and cons of doing that?
As far as I understand there are problems with preamble.
Basically what I would like to do is this - write a table to separate latex file and then include that in the document (I would be great if document header and footer came from LyX document.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to Insert > File > Child Document. See the section "7.2 Child Documents" in the Help > Embedded Objects manual. It explains how to insert `.lyx` files, `.tex` files, and `.txt` files (verbatim).

Comment: Thanks, this helped me.
As a sidenote to anybody who ever is puzzled about the same thing,   .tex file should not include his own preable, but only the content.

Comment: This seems to work, but it doesn't get the encoding right. That is, I'm using a UTF-8 encoded LaTeX document containing the word "Fiabilité" but it shows in the PDF that's rendered as "FiabilitÃ©". How can I tell LyX to respect the UTF-8 encoding of the child document?

Comment: I finally solved the above accent-related problem by changing Document > Settings > Language > Enoding > Other > Unicode (utf8). I had to do this for all the other Child documents that were in LyX as well. All of them were previously set to French, but if I input  a `.tex` document that uses utf8, all the related LyX documents have to have this encoding specifically.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator That's great you figured it out, thanks for sharing the solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\input{foo.tex}` or `\include{foo.tex}` to insert files containing only body text. But these two commands are different. Look for the difference.

Comment: Where is the relation to LyX?

Comment: @Daniel, does not LyX accept command line?

Comment: While it would be possible to write `\input{...}` or `\include{...}` commands into an ERT box, they would usually fail (if relative paths are used, which is good practice), as LyX generates and compiles everything inside a temporary folder. Hence, the mechanism built into LyX, described by scottkosty, is preferable. However, the point is that the answer, as given, is not really helpful anyway: It does not address the OPs issue and instead of writing "Look for the differences" it would be better to describe them briefly.

Comment: @Daniel, OK. I'll delete the usefulness answer.